# Adobe Acrobat DC Pro - How to move fields up when hiding fields with radio buttons

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I was wondering if I could get some help regarding my current issue with Adobe Acrobat DC Pro; I'm currently working on a PDF form and I'm hiding some fields via radio buttons I just created. I would like to know how can I move the fields up for not leaving an empty space of the hidden fields.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but will require a bit of programming, and all the elements which can be moved must be in fields.

The Field object has the rect property, which represents its coordinates. By accordingly modifying those coordinates, you can place (therefore move) the fields around.

You will create a function which evaluates all the radiobuttons values etc. and move the fields to the right place; you will call this function either from the radiobuttons, or from the Calculate event of a hidden, read-only field.